# Hide the column of wpf listview

Tags: wpf, listview

how to  make column invisible of wpf listview?
(one way is to set width property to minimum lenth but that not proper solution)
can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you post the definition of your listview?

Comment: Why do you need an invisible column? It sounds to me like you want to attach extra data to the row. If so, you can put the object in the row and use DataTemplates for rendering the text. Then the object itself is directly accessible as the list item.

Answer (score 9):

There is a pretty simple explanation of one way of doing it [here](http://i-zaak.eu/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5).

Find and remove your column:

```
var temp = myGridView.Columns[0];
myGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

Insert the column back in the view:

```
myGridView.Columns.Add(temp );
temp.Width = 0;
temp.Width = Double.NaN;
```

Remove it from the columns collection when you want to hide it and reinsert the column when you want to display it again.

Comment: My ListView does not have a Columns property. Also, your link is dead.

Comment: The Columns property is on the GridView (the View property of the ListView.)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the header of a ListView you can modify the Visibility property of the ColumnHeaderContainer by overriding the style locally.

```
<ListView>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
           <Style>
               <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
           </Style>
        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
        <GridView.Columns>
            ...
        </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? OP is actually asking how to show/hide an entire column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this will help someone:

The best way I have found is to do these two things:
1. Set the width of the column to 0 (this can be done in the GridViewColumnHeader as well) - change it in code when you want to show the column again.
2. Set the Visibility setting of the GridViewColumnHeader to Hidden - set it in code if you want to show the column again or you can even use a binding.

The second item above helps to make the column non-expandable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

To hide a column you can set the column width to zero, and disable the header, like this:

Set GridViewColumn Width and set GridViewColumnHeader IsEnabled to False.

Example:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ColumnWidth, Mode=OneWay}">
<GridViewColumnHeader Content="Nº Item" IsEnabled="False" />
```