# ListView's Column Visibility Hidding Issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, listview, gridview

I want to set the visibility of col1 this is actually GridView's column and Gridview is inside the ListView so I Want to set hide and visible col1 through code behind how it's work..

```
    <ListView
        Height="530"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyContainer}"
        x:Name="dgPorfomance">
        <ListView.View >
            <GridView >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col1" Width="Auto" Header="Check" CellTemplate="{StaticResource dtChkID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Width="50" Header="ID" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="200" Header="Name" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}" Width="200" Header="Address" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col5" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City}" Width="200" Header="City" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col6" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pin}" Width="200" Header="Pin" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="col7" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}" Width="200" Header="Phone" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Thanks..!!

Comment: It's unclear whether you're using a `ListView` or `GridView` control. They're not the same thing. Your original tag and title said one thing, while your question itself said another.

Comment: I am using ListView and inside the ListView.View and adding the GrideView, I have four column and I want Hide the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

[Hide the column of wpf listview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/823789/217880)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/30b7ed89-2ae1-451f-922a-b82078129a0c

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the column to make it invisible:

```
dgPorfomance.Columns.Remove(dgPorfomance.Columns[0])
```